# Passing data through constructors getting null

Tags: flutter

I am passing data to other widgets using constructors.

I have a Shop Screen where I am getting the data from server. This shop screen consists of cards. On click of any card a details screen opens. I am passing data from shop screen to details screen using constructors. The details screen has many child widgets. For example I have images and text in the upper part of the screen as one widget and the other half of the screen consists of two tabs. I am getting proper data for images and text which is first widget but am getting null data in the second widget when I open it for the first time. The second time I open any other card I get data for the first click.

This is how I am passing the data from the first i.e shop screen:

```
  Navigator.of(context)
                          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                        return Detail(
                          id: shop[index].id,
                          shopList: shopWithList,
                        );
                      }));
```

Please help!

Comment: How do you go back?

Comment: @TinusJackson Using the back button

Comment: @USER9561 can you show more of your components?

Comment: better post your complete shop code and details page on Pastebin and share the link

Comment: @USER9561 can you please post the code where you are supposed to accept the data you passed ?